# Location of file in magento - Credit Memo email

Tags: file, magento, location

Trying to find the location of

sales_email_order_creditmemo_items

to customise the transactional emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fulltextsearch for `sales_email_order_creditmemo_items` reveals, where the block is defined in your layout xml. By default the template is located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml`.